# Why does --default-character-set=utf8mb4 have no impact on the client connection?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, mysql-cli

According to https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/charset-connection.html, When I connect to a mysql 5.6 server with the mysql 8.0 client using the command:

`/usr/bin/mysql -h ${DB_HOST} -u ${DB_USER} -p --default-character-set=utf8mb4`

I expect that the client will set up a utf8mb4 connection to the server. However, the connection is set to latin1:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SESSION_VARIABLES WHERE VARIABLE_NAME IN (
 'character_set_client', 'character_set_connection', 'character_set_results', 'collation_connection' ) 
ORDER BY VARIABLE_NAME;
+--------------------------+-------------------+
| VARIABLE_NAME            | VARIABLE_VALUE    |
+--------------------------+-------------------+
| CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT     | latin1            |
| CHARACTER_SET_CONNECTION | latin1            |
| CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS    | latin1            |
| COLLATION_CONNECTION     | latin1_swedish_ci |
+--------------------------+-------------------+
```

Using another character set, like:
`/usr/bin/mysql -h ${DB_HOST} -u ${DB_USER} -p --default-character-set=koi8r` will result in the client connecting with the supplied character set:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SESSION_VARIABLES WHERE VARIABLE_NAME IN ( 'character_set_client', 'character_set_connection', 'character_set_results', 'collation_connection' ) ORDER BY VARIABLE_NAME;
+--------------------------+------------------+
| VARIABLE_NAME            | VARIABLE_VALUE   |
+--------------------------+------------------+
| CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT     | koi8r            |
| CHARACTER_SET_CONNECTION | koi8r            |
| CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS    | koi8r            |
| COLLATION_CONNECTION     | koi8r_general_ci |
+--------------------------+------------------+
```

The only way I can get the client connection to change is by executing `charset utf8mb4` or `SET NAMES utf8mb4` AFTER connecting to the server.

```
mysql> SET NAMES utf8mb4;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SESSION_VARIABLES WHERE VARIABLE_NAME IN ( 'character_set_client', 'character_set_connection', 'character_set_results', 'collation_connection' ) ORDER BY VARIABLE_NAME;
+--------------------------+--------------------+
| VARIABLE_NAME            | VARIABLE_VALUE     |
+--------------------------+--------------------+
| CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT     | utf8mb4            |
| CHARACTER_SET_CONNECTION | utf8mb4            |
| CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS    | utf8mb4            |
| COLLATION_CONNECTION     | utf8mb4_general_ci |
+--------------------------+--------------------+
```

Why will --default-character-set=utf8mb4 not work? I want to use other client tools like mysqldump and mysqlimport but without this flag I will get latin1 encoding instead of utf8mb4 encoding. Changing default server settings is not an option in this situation, it must be done from the client.

Some more information: I'm trying this from a 20.04 ubuntu WSL2 install, so there is no 5.6 or 5.7 client available. However, using a 5.6 or 5.7 windows mysql client will respect --default-character-set=utf8mb4, but the 8.0 windows client has the same behavior as the WSL2 client.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behavior is explained in the 8.0 documentation: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-connection.html

> The same problem occurs in a more subtle context: When the client tells the server to use a character set that the server recognizes,
> but the default collation for that character set on the client side is
> not known on the server side. This occurs, for example, when a MySQL
> 8.0 client wants to connect to a MySQL 5.7 server using utf8mb4 as the client character set. A client that specifies
> --default-character-set=utf8mb4 is able to connect to the server. However, as in the previous example, the server falls back to its
> default character set and collation, not what the client requested:
>
> ```
>    mysql> SHOW SESSION VARIABLES LIKE 'character\_set\_%';
>    +--------------------------+--------+ 
>    | Variable_name            | Value  |
>    +--------------------------+--------+
>    | character_set_client     | latin1 | 
>    | character_set_connection | latin1 | 
>    ...
>    |character_set_results    | latin1 | 
>    ...
>    +--------------------------+--------+ 
>    mysql> SHOW SESSION VARIABLES LIKE 'collation_connection';
>    +----------------------+-------------------+ 
>    | Variable_name        | Value             |
>    +----------------------+-------------------+ 
>    | collation_connection | latin1_swedish_ci |
>    +----------------------+-------------------+
> ```
>
> Why does this occur? After all, utf8mb4 is known to the 8.0 client and the 5.7 server, so
> both of them recognize it. To understand this behavior, it is
> necessary to understand that when the client tells the server which
> character set it wants to use, it really tells the server the default
> collation for that character set. Therefore, the aforementioned
> behavior occurs due to a combination of factors:
>
> - The default collation for utf8mb4 differs between MySQL 5.7 and 8.0
>   (utf8mb4_general_ci for 5.7, utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci for 8.0).
> - When the 8.0 client requests a character set of utf8mb4, what it sends
>   to the server is the default 8.0 utf8mb4 collation; that is, the
>   utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci.
> - utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci is implemented only as of MySQL 8.0, so the 5.7
>   server does not recognize it.
> - Because the 5.7 server does not recognize utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci, it
>   cannot satisfy the client character set request, and falls back to its
>   default character set and collation (latin1 and latin1_swedish_ci).
>
> In this case, the client can still use utf8mb4 by issuing a SET NAMES
> 'utf8mb4' statement after connecting. The resulting collation is the
> 5.7 default utf8mb4 collation; that is, utf8mb4_general_ci. If the client additionally wants a collation of utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci, it cannot
> achieve that because the server does not recognize that collation. The
> client must either be willing to use a different utf8mb4 collation, or
> connect to a server from MySQL 8.0 or higher.